# Joomla images folder permission for Media Manager

Tags: image, joomla, permissions, backend

I am having some trouble with the Media Manager on Joomla 3.3.6.
My folder permissions for /images and down are all 755 and my files 644 since that is recommended. But when I try to upload files using the backend Media Manager I get:

```
Warning: Failed to move file!
```

and

```
Error. Unable to upload file.
```

Setting my folder and file permissions for /images to 777 fixes the problem of course but that is bad practice, correct?

Can anyone help me out why it won't work with 755 and 644? It should, right?

Edit: I have not enabled FTP in the Global Configuration. Is that necessary for using the proper permissions?

Comment: Please ask your question on the dedicated [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site ;)

Comment: @Lodder Thanks, I didn't even know there was one! Sorry for posting it here :)